# How to deploy java app for Windows pc

Tags: java

I have studied Java Web Start and found it complex and clumsy for my purposes.  In addition, my app needs to access the PC resources, which causes more hoops to be jumped through with Java Web Start.  To add to the difficulties I need to access a 32-bit native library (libvlc) so I need to insure that my app runs under 32-bit Java.  Is there an easy way to deploy my app without resorting to Java Web Start?  Needless to say, I want everything to be contained in a single .exe file.

Comment: *"Needless to say, I want everything to be contained in a single .exe file."*  Needless to say, it won't work on anything but Windows.  Why the attraction of coding in Java, if only targeting Windows?

Comment: I am reusing a lot of Java code from my associated Android app.  In addition, the native library (libvlc) will only work for Windows.  Later I will come out with other versions of my app that will use the native libraries for other platforms.

Comment: BTW - a digitally signed JWS app. can fulfill the stated requirements.  For an example of digitally signing an app., see my little [File service demo.](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).  The demo. uses the JNLP API to access the local file-system rather than the J2SE `File`, but that is not the point - the point is the build file digitally signs the code.  Further, a bit of searching suggests the [native is also available for Linux](http://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial).  JWS can partition the download for Windows/Linux (sorry Mac. users!).

Comment: Thanks, I had read about this capability.  It just seemed like a little more than I wanted to bite off at this time.  I'll definitely look into it further when I have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by searching the Internet for keywords such as "`java 2 exe`" and "`jar to exe`", etc.  Doing so yields many freely available software packages that convert Java programs into Windows executables, for example:

- JexePack - http://www.duckware.com/jexepack/index.html
- JarToExe - http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/
- JSmooth - http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

And the list goes on.  Perhaps one of them meets your needs?

Comment: JarToExe is the only one that I tried.  Its wizard makes things very easy.  However, JexePack also looks good for a command line program and the shareware pricing looks reasonable.  JSmooth also appears to have a wizard but does not seem to have as many features as JarToExe.  It also appears to be free.  Thanks for pointing these out.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question to help people understand how to do this, which has taken me some number of days to figure out.

My initial problem was that my app would run on some versions of Windows but on others it was having problems finding the libvlc native library.  I finally figured out that my app must run with 32-bit Java in order to use the 32-bit native library.  Thus, the problem then became how to insure that the user started my app with 32-bit Java.

I read about Jar2Exe (http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/) in another post and decided to check it out.  It is a great little program that is very configurable so I figured that it must be able to handle my 32-bit Java problem.  In fact, it does so without even needing to do any configuration.  The resulting .exe file contains my app along with all the required jar files and starts up with the 32-bit Java.  I am very pleased with this program and plan to buy a license, which is very cheap.

Hope this saves time for other people who are trying to solve a similar problem.